# Byte slice is changing by self

Tags: go

I am trying to realise encryption, and I have a problem with the byte slice of the original text. In the beginning it has correct value, but after I use encrypt function it is changing and I don't know why. Please help. Here is small part of my code with output:

```
func main() {
    str := "Hello it's me, a Mario!!"
    text := []byte(str)

    keys := magmaExpandKey([]byte("asdfghjklz,cmvnfkwadmandksjtmdolasdasdf"))

    var crypted []byte

//First block just for example
    fmt.Printf("Original: %b\n", text[0:8])
    crypted = magmaEncrypt(text[0:8], keys)
    fmt.Printf("Original: %b\n", text[0:8])

/* Output:
Original: [1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1101001 1110100]
Original: [1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 11000011 1101001 11001110 1010111]
*/


    fmt.Printf("Crypted: %s\n", crypted)
    fmt.Printf("Decrypted: %s\n", magmaDecrypt(crypted, keys))
}

func magmaEncrypt(blk []byte, keys []roundKey) []byte {
    var crypted []byte

    crypted = magmaG(keys[0].Key, blk)

    for i := 1; i < 31; i++ {
        crypted = magmaG(keys[i].Key, crypted)
    }

    crypted = magmaG(keys[31].Key, crypted)

    return crypted
}
```

[Full code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Jt1cLhfk)

Comment: We need `magmaG` source code. That function is probably altering the `blk` variable.

Comment: Updated the question, added link on pastebin. But I do not understand, yep it is altering `blk`, but I do not use pointers.

Comment: Please read up on [slice internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro#:~:text=Slice%20internals&text=It%20consists%20of%20a%20pointer,referred%20to%20by%20the%20slice.). A slice is just a small descriptor pointing to an underlying array. Passing the descriptor around by value does not copy the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `magmaG` returns `append(left, right)`, where `left` is at that point is pointing to `blk[4:8]`. When `blk` has enough capacity, this `append` overwrites the underlying array of `blk` causing the "original" contents to change in the slightly unpredictable way you're seeing.

From your pastebin link, the `magmaG` function looks like this:

```
func magmaG(k []byte, a []byte) []byte {
    var left []byte
    var right []byte
    var G []byte

    // Делим 64-битный исходный блок на две части
    left = a[0:4]
    right = a[4:8]

    // Производим преобразование g
    G = magma_g(k, right)

    // Ксорим результат преобразования g с левой половиной блока
    G = magmaAddXor(left, G)

    // Пишем в левую половину значение из правой
    left = right

    // Пишем результат GOST_Magma_Add в правую половину блока
    right = G

    // Сводим правую и левую части блока в одно целое
    return append(left, right...)
}
```

A simple change would be to replace the final line with `return append(append([]byte{}, left...), right...)` which constructs a byte slice from a new empty backing array.

I note that your code can be significantly simplified by removing all the intermediate variables:

```
func magmaG(k, a []byte) []byte {
    G := magma_g(k, a[4:8])
    G = magmaAddXor(a[:4], G)
    return append(append(make([]byte, 0, 8), a[4:8]...), G...)
}
```